# Is there a way to abort loading of external js files that my website provider includes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, external

Is it possible for javascript I include to cause the downloading of other external js files to abort so my page load and render time isn't affected by them?

I'm using a site builder called AgentFire that's based on Wordpress.  There are external js and css files that the site builder includes automatically in every site built with their software.  I can add my own external js and css files but I don't have access to delete any scripts the developer includes.  Some of these files are for features that I'm not using so downloading and running them is unnessessarily slowing my page load and rendering times.

I asked the developer to delete the unused external files from my site but they refuse.  I think they don't want to make that an option for all the sites built using thier product as it would probably lead to a bunch of tech support requests when features that require the files don't work properly.

Comment: Try the [wp_dequeue_script function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/). [This article](https://devpress.com/how-to-dequeue-scripts-and-styles-in-wordpress-for-improved-page-speed/) might provide helpful explanation.

Comment: Thanks Brett.  However, I forgot to mention that the developer won't allow me to install plugins either.

Comment: Sounds like you need a different provider

Comment: Agreed.  I should probably recreate my website within Wordpress only so I have control and can optimize for my own needs.  However, that's a multimonth project that I can't start until next winter.  Looking for a short-term solution to get me by until then.

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s not possible for

> Javascript I include to cause the downloading of other external js
> files to abort.

However, if your website

- is using a domain that you control, and
- the external js files that you want to block are hosted on that same domain ...

... then you may be able to create a rule to block access to those files at your hosting provider, or, if you use a proxy such as Cloudflare in front of your website, you could block access there with a firewall rule or page rule.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can really block it is to block it in the hardware and block it via the router and/or server.  Otherwise, no.